# Copy of polygon created in matlab figure despite using same figure handle throughout

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

```
    figure;
    poly = fill(sq(:,1), sq(:,2), 'b');
    %% create cell "p" consisting of 5600 arrays of same size as sq
    for i=1:5600
        hold on
        set(poly, 'X', p{i}(:,1),...
            'Y', p{i}(:,2));
        hold off
        drawnow;
    end
    %% again create cell "q" consisting of 8700 arrays of same size as sq
    for i=1:8700
        hold on
        set(poly, 'X', q{i}(:,1),...
            'Y', q{i}(:,2));
        hold off
        drawnow;
    end
```

I create a blue-filled polygon in first line and then move it all over the figure. When i run the above code, first section moves a polygon as controlled by `p` from initial point x0 to x1. Then i make another cell `q` in second section of code and use it to move blue-filled polygon again from x1 to x2. But this time a copy of the polygon is created at x1 which moves so that the previous polygon is still at x1 while this new polygon is moving to x2. Why is this happening?

Comment: What you have looks right (though maybe you should use the full property names `XData` and `YData` instead of just `X` and `Y`). Is it possible that the data in `q` contains a copy of the old polygon?

Comment: @KQS I create q from scratch. It does not contain old data. And i use hold on/off commands also that i have updated in the above snippet.

Comment: Does adding a `pause(0.01)` to the loop help? This can help rule out graphics synchronization issues.

Comment: @KQS No I still get the copies made.

Comment: @KQS Is there a way i can find the handle to the old copy and delete the polygon?

Comment: In this code, you only ever make one polygon object (called a "patch" object in the MATLAB documentation), and `poly` is the handle to that object. So there should only be one copy. The fact that it works for the 1st loop makes it all the more confusing. My suspicion is that there's something about `q`, but I can't really help with that. If you think there's multiple patch objects, then you can try clicking on the "old" one and using `gco` to get a handle to what you just clicked on.

Comment: this works for now: `delete(findall(h,'Type','Patch'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write what you describe, using a little different code (more efficient), and made up the parts you didn't add. It's working, so if this is what you look for you can either adopt this code or compare it with yours and look for the problem.

My code:

```
% define some parameters and auxilary function:
sq_size = 3;
makeSq = @(xy) [xy(1) xy(2)
    xy(1)+sq_size xy(2)
    xy(1)+sq_size xy(2)+sq_size
    xy(1) xy(2)+sq_size];

% create the first object:
sq = makeSq([1 1]);
poly = fill(sq(:,1), sq(:,2), 'b');

% setting the limmits for a constant view:
xlim([0 50+sq_size])
ylim([0 50+sq_size])

% first loop:
p = randi(50,10,2); % no need for cell here...
for k = 1:size(p,1)
    temp_sq = makeSq(p(k,:));
    set(poly, 'X', temp_sq(:,1),'Y',temp_sq(:,2));
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1)
end

% second loop:
q = randi(50,20,2); % no need for cell here...
set(poly,'FaceColor','g') % change to green to see we are in the second loop
for k = 1:size(q,1)
    temp_sq = makeSq(q(k,:));
    set(poly,'X',temp_sq(:,1),'Y',temp_sq(:,2));
    drawnow;
    pause(0.1)
end
```

The `pause` is only so you see the animation, it's not really needed.